# How to read list of key:values returned by !GetAtt in cloudformation for AWS Network Firewall

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to access 3 network firewall endpoints that gets created in 3 subnets in different AZs to be added to route tables:

Logical name of network firewall is "NetworkFirewall"

````
!GetAtt NetworkFirewall.EndpointIds.${AWS::Region}b
!GetAtt NetworkFirewall.EndpointIds.${AWS::Region}c```

As specified in AWS docs:

Fn::GetAtt
The Fn::GetAtt intrinsic function returns a value for a specified attribute of this type. The following are the available attributes and sample return values.

For more information about using the Fn::GetAtt intrinsic function, see Fn::GetAtt.

EndpointIds
The unique IDs of the firewall endpoints for all of the subnets that you attached to the firewall. The subnets are not listed in any particular order. For example: **["us-west-2c:vpce-111122223333", "us-west-2a:vpce-987654321098", "us-west-2b:vpce-012345678901"]**.

But this way:
!GetAtt NetworkFirewall.EndpointIds.${AWS::Region}a
of accessing endpoints, seems to be not working.

Any tips will be helpfull
````

Comment: I tried
```!GetAtt NetworkFirewall.EndpointIds``` which would return list of 3 key:value pairs, from which I need to extract networkfirewall endpoints for each AZ's and use them in related route table, using Cloudformation

Comment: Sorry, its not clear what you want to achieve. Its a list, so you select them by indices, not any key words, nor region names.

Comment: Hi, Problem I am facing, is that its list of randomly sorted key:value, such that I don't know whether 1 element is AZa or AZb or AZc. Hence I cannot simply use ```Fn::Select``` and ```Fn::Split``` function, because they are not sorted and I cannot use them in route table for AZa, AZb or AZc, as it is

Answer (score 0):

As you already observed, you can't do what you want to do. CloudFormation (CFN) simply does not support such operations like searching a list.

If you want to keep using CFN, the only way to achieve you want is through a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). In your case you would have to develop such a resource, in a form of a **lambda function**, which would do the custom search and filtering of the `EndpointIds` for you.

The alternative is not to use CFN. You can try using other Infrastructure as Code tools. For example, in terraform such operations that you want are natural and easily achievable.

Answer (score 0):

For the single AZ setup it's possible using CFN intrinsic functions:

```
VpcEndpointId: !Select ["1", !Split [":", !Select ["0", !GetAtt NetworkFirewall.EndpointIds]]]
```

credits to https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-studio-vpc-networkfirewall/blob/master/cfn_templates/vpc.yaml#L236

However single-AZ is not resilient.

For multi-AZ a custom Lambda-backed resource is needed, as follows:

```
NetworkFirewallEndpointsFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Description: Custom resource to transform NetworkFirewall EndpointIds
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Timeout: 10
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      FunctionName: transform-networkfirewall-endpointids
      Code:
          ZipFile: |
              import cfnresponse
              def lambda_handler(event, context):
                response = {}
                try:
                  kwEndpointIds = {f"Id{eid.split(':')[0][-1].upper()}": eid.split(':')[-1] for eid in event['ResourceProperties']['EndpointIds']}
                  response = kwEndpointIds
                except:
                  response = ''
                
                cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, response, "kwEndpointIds")

NetworkFirewallEndpoints:
    Type: Custom::NetworkFirewallEndpoints
    Properties:
        ServiceToken: !GetAtt NetworkFirewallEndpointsFunction.Arn
        EndpointIds: !GetAtt NetworkFirewall.EndpointIds

RouteA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
        ...
        VpcEndpointId: !GetAtt NetworkFirewallEndpoints.IdA

RouteB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
        ...
        VpcEndpointId: !GetAtt NetworkFirewallEndpoints.IdB
```